# PHP variable increment loop not working

Tags: php, arrays, loops, increment

Ok i cant see whats wrong in this function, all array values work fine and the rest not, for some reason i cant see, any help will be apreciated.

```
<?php
                //formato do array $colunas ['Nome do Header'] => array('tipo de formatação a retornar','titulo da coluna no banco','substring' , 'mostrar padrao', 'largura da coluna')
                $colunas = array(
                '#'=>array('nenhuma','contagem',0,0,0),
                'Id'=>array('nenhuma','id',0,0,0),
                'Nome do Cliente'=>array('nenhuma','nome',0,0,0),
                );
                renderdatatable('SELECT id,nome FROM #__metafacil_clientes', $colunas); ?>
```

This is the call of the function that ill paste below

```
function renderdatatable($query, $colunas) {

$keys = array_keys($colunas);
$qtde_colunas = count($keys);
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery($query);
$campos = $db->loadAssocList();

if (empty($campos)) {
    //retornar um template inicial para o cliente...
} else {
    echo '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dTableR"><thead><tr>';
    for ($c=1;$c<=$qtde_colunas;$c++) {
        $d = $c-1;
        echo '<th>'.$keys[$d].'</th>';
    }
    echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';
    $numerolinha = 1;
    foreach ($campos as $campo){
        echo '<tr>';
        for($i=1;$i<=$qtde_colunas;$i++) {
            echo '<td>';
            //usamos o $l = $i-1 para acessar o vetor contendo o tipo de campo e switch para formatá-lo onde $campo e a linha retornada pela consulta com chave de array alfanumerico
            $l = $i-1;
            $chavecoluna = $keys[$l];
            $coluna = $colunas[$chavecoluna][1];
            switch ($coluna) {
                case 'imagem':
                    $value = formata_imagem($campo[$coluna]);
                    break;
                case 'contagem':
                    $value = $numerolinha;
                default:
                    $value = $campo[$coluna];
            }
            //fecha a celula
            echo $value;
            echo '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
        $numerolinha = $numerolinha+1;
    }
    echo '</tbody></table>';
}
```

}

This function have the objective of render a table, as my system will need a lot of different tables, i'm pardonizing this function so i dont need to write the query every single time a page is loaded

All is working fine except the $numerolinha variable that is not showing in the array for reason i dont know....why is not working any help?

its a joomla function by the way

Comment: in your switch case any of your $coluna equals to 'contagem'?

Comment: Lemme perform a check

Comment: Shoulb be only the $colunas['#'][1] as you can see the loop

Comment: can you `print_r()` or `var_dump()` the `$campos` array and paste it here?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [nome] => Paulo José ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [nome] => Pedro Augusto ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [nome] => CANAFIH ) )

Comment: Found the solution thanks for your time =)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the missing break just below this line

$value = $numerolinha;

Thanks bagovyi for your support!!

Comment: Ah, didn't catch that one! Nice :)